# Non replaying hot observable

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, subject

#### Original question

I have a scenario where I have multiple `IObservable` sequences which I want to combine with `Merge` and then listen to. However, if one of these produces an error I don't want it to crash everything for the other streams, as well as to resubscribe to the sequence (this is an 'ever lasting' sequence).

I do this by appending a `Retry()` to the streams before merge, i.e.:

```
IEnumerable<IObservable<int>> observables = GetObservables();

observables
    .Select(o => o.Retry())
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(/* Do subscription stuff */);
```

However, the problem arises when I want to test this. What I would like to test is that if one of the `IObservable`s in `observables` produces an `OnError`, the other ones should still be able to send their values through and they should get handled

I thought I'd just use two `Subject<int>`s representing two `IObservable`s in `observables`; one sending an `OnError(new Exception())` and the other, after that, sending `OnNext(1)`. However, it seems `Subject<int>` will replay all previous values for a new subscription (which effectively `Retry()` is), turning the test into an infinite loop.

I tried to solve it by creating a manual `IObservable` that produces an error on the first subscription and later an empty sequence, but it feels hacky:

```
var i = 0;
var nErrors = 2;
var testErrorObservableWithOneErrorAndThenCompletion = Observable.Create<int>(o => {
    i++;
    if (i < nErrors) {
        return Observable.Throw<int>(new Exception()).Subscribe(o);
    } else {
        return Observable.Empty<int>().Subscribe(o);
    }
});
```

Am I using `Subject` or thinking about `Retry()` in the wrong way? Any other thoughts on this? How would you solve this situation?

#### Update

Ok, here's a marble diagram of what I want and *think* `Retry()` does.

```
o = message, X = error.
------o---o---X
               \
     Retry() -> \---o---o---X
                             \
                   Retry() -> \...
```

My problem is perhaps more in that I don't have a good stock class to use fore testing, since `Subject` wants to replay all of my previous errors.

#### Update 2

Here's a test case that shows what I mean about `Subject` replaying its values. Am I using the term correctly if I say it does this in a *cold* way? I know `Subject` is a way of creating a hot observable, but still this behavior feels 'cold' to me.

```
var onNext = false;
var subject = new Subject<int>();

subject.Retry().Subscribe(x => onNext = true);
subject.OnError(new Exception());
subject.OnNext(1);

Assert.That(onNext, Is.True);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your updated requirements (you want to retry the observables that fail, rather than just wanting to ignore them), we can come up with a solution that works.

First, it's important to understand the difference between a cold observable (recreated on every subscription) and a hot observable (exists regardless of subscriptions). You can't `Retry()` a hot observable, as it won't know how to recreate the underlying events. That is, if a hot observable errors, it's gone forever.

`Subject` creates a hot observable, in the sense that you can call `OnNext` without having subscribers and it will act as expected. To convert a hot observable to a cold observable, you can use `Observable.Defer`, which will contain the 'creation on subscription' logic for that observable.

All that said, here's the original code modified to do this:

```
var success = new Subject<int>();
var error = new Subject<int>();

var observables = new List<IObservable<int>> { Observable.Defer(() => {success = new Subject<int>(); return success.AsObservable();}), 
                                               Observable.Defer(() => {error = new Subject<int>(); return error.AsObservable();}) };                                            

observables
.Select(o => o.Retry())
.Merge()
.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("done"));
```

And the test (similar to before):

```
success.OnNext(1);
error.OnError(new Exception("test"));
success.OnNext(2);
error.OnNext(-1);
success.OnCompleted();
error.OnCompleted();
```

And the output as expected:

```
1
2
-1
done
```

Of course, you'll need to modify this concept significantly depending on what you're underlying observable is. Using subjects for testing is not the same as using them for real.

I also want to note that this comment:

> However, it seems Subject will replay all previous values for a
>   new subscription (which effectively Retry() is), turning the test into
>   an infinite loop.

Is not true - `Subject` doesn't behave this way. There is some other aspect of your code that is causing the infinite loop based on the fact that `Retry` recreates the subscription, and the subscription creates an error at some point.

---

**Original answer** (for completion)

The issue is that `Retry()` doesn't do what you want it to do. From here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708141(v=vs.92).aspx

> Repeats the source observable sequence for retryCount times or until
>   it successfully terminates.

This means that `Retry` will continually try and reconnect to the underlying observable until it succeeds and doesn't throw an error.

My understanding is that you actually want exceptions in the observable to be **ignored**, not retried. This will do what you want instead:

```
observables
.Select(o => o.Catch((Func<Exception,IObservable<int>>)(e => Observable.Empty<int>())))
.Merge()
.Subscribe(/* subscription code */);
```

This uses `Catch` to trap the observable with an exception, and replace it with an empty observable at that point.

Here is a full test using subjects:

```
var success = new Subject<int>();
var error = new Subject<int>();

var observables = new List<IObservable<int>> { success.AsObservable(), error.AsObservable() };

observables
.Select(o => o.Catch((Func<Exception,IObservable<int>>)(e => Observable.Empty<int>())))
.Merge()
.Subscribe(Observer.Create<int>(Console.WriteLine, Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("done")));

success.OnNext(1);
error.OnError(new Exception("test"));
success.OnNext(2);
success.OnCompleted();
```

And this produces, as expected:

```
1
2
done
```

Comment: But I don't want to stop observing that sequence, I want a way to, as you say, ignore exceptions, but still continue to use that source. I though that was what `Retry()` was for. I've updated the question with a marble diagram.

Comment: @seldon I've updated the answer, the problem is somewhat subtle but it's important you understand it completely before applying it to your exact situation.

Comment: Yes, `Observable.Defer()` is actually what I wanted, except I did it 'manually' with `Observable.Create()`. Thanks! About `Subject` not replaying its errors when `Retry()` is applied to it; I might not understand exactly what you're meaning. I added a test case which demonstrates what I mean. It will never reach the `Assert` but continue infinitely.

Comment: It never reaches `Assert` because it's undefined what happens when you try and resubscribe to a hot observable (I believe it's undefined anyway). If you did a `Console.WriteLine` on the `Subscribe` you'll see that it doesn't sit there in an infinite loop - rather, it hangs. That 'hang' happens when `Retry()` tries to `Subscribe` on the now dead subject.