# RxJava 2.0 - handling ressources for uncaught subsciber error in publish().refCount()

Tags: java, exception, rx-java, rx-java2

I am rather new to RxJava and - as so many others - am trying to get my head around exception handling. I read quite a few post online (e.g. this discussion here [how to handle exceptions thrown by observer's onNext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344320/how-to-handle-exceptions-thrown-by-observers-onnext-in-rxjava)) and *think* that I get the basic idea of the concepts.

In the above mentioned discussion, one of the posters says, that when an exception is thrown in a subscriber, RxJava does the following:

> Implement generic handling to log the failure and stop sending it events 
>   (of any kind) and clean up any resources due to that subscriber and carry 
>   on with any remaining subscriptions.

This is also more or less what I see, the only thing I have problems with is the "clean up any ressources" bit. To make that clear, let's assume the following example:

I want to create an Observable that listens to an async event source (e.g. a JMS queue) and onNext()s on every received message. So in (pseudo-) code I would do something similar to this:

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.create( s -> {
  createConnectionToBroker();
  getConsumer().setMessageListener(message -> s.onNext(transform(message)));
  s.setDisposable(new Disposable() {
    public void dispose() {
      tearDownBrokerConnection();
    }
  });
});
```

Since I want to reuse the message listener for many subscribers / observers, I do not directly subscribe at the created Observable, but make use of the publish().refCount() team instead. Something similar to this:

```
Observable<String> observableToSubscribeTo = observable.publish().refCount();

Disposable d1 = observableToSubscribeTo.subscribe(s -> ...);
Disposable d2 = observableToSubscribeTo.subscribe(s -> ...);
```

This all works as expected. The code connects to JMS only when the first subscription is established, and the connection to the broker is closed when the last observer was `dispose()`d.

**However**, when a subscriber throws an exception when it is `onNext()`ed, things seem to get messy. As expected, the observer that threw is nuked, and whenever a new event is published, it won't be notified anymore. My problem appears that when all the remaining subscribers are `dispose()`d, the Observable that maintains the connection to the message broker is no longer notified. It looks to me as if the subscriber that threw the exception is in some sort of zombie state. It is ignored when it comes to event distribution, but it somehow prevents the root Observable to get notified when the last subscriber is `dispose()`d.

I understand that RxJava expects the observers to make sure to not throw but rather handle an eventual exception properly. Unfortunately, in the case where I want to provide a library that returns an Observable to the caller, I have no control over my subscribers whatsoever. This means, I would never be able to protect my library against stupid observers.

So, I am asking myself: am I missing something here? Is there really no  chance to properly cleanup when a subscriber throws? Is this a bug or is it just me not understanding the library?

Any insights greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you could show some unit tests that demonstrates the problem (without the need for JMS) that would be great.

Also, onNext in RxJava 2 should never throw; if it does it is an undefined behavior. If you don't trust your consumers, you can have an end-observable transformer that does `safeSubscribe` instead of the plain `subscribe` that adds protecting against misbehaving downstream:

```
.compose(o -> v -> o.safeSubscribe(v))
```

or

```
.compose(new ObservableTransformer<T>() {
    @Override public Observable<T> apply(final Observable<T> source) {
        return new Observable<T>() {
            @Override public void subscribeActual(Observer<? super T> observer) {
                 source.safeSubscribe(observer);
            }
        };
    }
})
```

Comment: hi @akarnokd,

thanks for looking into this! I just wrote a basic unit test to demonstrate the behavior, just to learn that I am no longer able to reproduce it?!?! :-o Pretty embarrassing, I must say :-( So I can just assume that the problem was somewhere in my glue code. Apologies for wasting your time!!!

And thanks for the comments regarding safeSubscribe(). Since as a library you can never trust the using code, I would really like to harden it. One misbehaving subscriber should not have any side effects on other well behaving ones.